# Keeping divs on one line in css

Tags: css, html, alignment

I just want to know the actions you need in order to keep divs on the same line as each other.  Refer me to a good article too if you can, I'd like to try to read up on this stuff..

Here is my project: `http://jsfiddle.net/kDrJL/11/`

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/kDrJL/11/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want the #header and the #register on the same line.  #header floating in center and #nav floating on the right.

Comment: You have a typo in #header css. Display should be ```inline-block```. Add a margin and you're good to go

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kDrJL/11/  It is not centering.  The header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I could probably muddle my way through an answer to this I'd, instead, like to direct you to an answer given by Acorn to another question.  They answered this better than I can:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008699/1764462